# How can i select an element by not containing span puppeteer

Tags: javascript, html, puppeteer

i am trying to select the first element which doesn't contain the span: `Geef seintje` from a dropdown menu. I tried the code below, this piece of code selects the first element that contains `Geef seintje` but how can i make it that it selects the first element that doesn't contain this span?

```
const elements = await page.$x('//div[@role="presentation"][.//span[.="Geef seintje"]]');
console.log('found')
await elements[0].click();
```

The html can be find on https://www.zalando.nl/jordan-air-jordan-1-mid-sneakers-hoog-joc12n001-a18.html and then pressing the size dropdown menu, below is also a picture of the html. The only difference in the elements is that the one which are sold out contain an extra class which contains the span: `Geef seintje`.

[picture of html](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xzsgB.png)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `not` in your xpath to say that it doesn't contain some text, and `page.waitForXPath` whic return a single element (the first) instead of `page.$x` which returns all matching elements:

```js
const firstElement = await page.waitForXPath("//span[not(contains(text(), 'Geef seintje'))]//ancestor::div[@role='presentation']");
```

Comment: Hi! Thanks for your answer but it doesn't work sadly. I used what you suggested in a try catch but it doesn't seem to find it because it doesn't perform my console.log('found')